# How to execute generated script(.sql file) with schema and data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SSMS 2008 I am able to generate a script for a database with huge amounts of data in file `ABC.sql` on my desktop.

The database has approx. 9 GB of data so I'm unable to open the file. Is there any way to execute the script?

When I try to open it in SSMS I get an error:

> The operation could not be completed. not enough storage is available to complete this operation
>
> The template specified cannot be found. Please check that the full path is correct

Comment: For huge databases more preferable used a backup.

Comment: @Devart ....really thnks, I have already used all possible options like backup,copy,import/export wizard,but they din't help me.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server offers 2 command prompt features that can se used for executing large queries - osql (will be removed in future), and sqlcmd

[osql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) is located in the Tools\Binn subfolder. To execute a SQL script:

1. Start the Command Prompt
2. Navigate to the folder where the osql utility is located
3. Run the command in the following format:

   osql –H <workstation name> -S <server_name[\instance_name]> -U <user login ID> -P <login password> –i <full path to script>

To execute the large.sql file located in the D:\test, against the Central database on the SQL Server instance Dell\SQL2012, as an sa with the 'sqladmin' password, run the following command:

osql -H Dell -S Dell\SQL2012 -i D:\test\large.sql -U sa -P sqladmin

The [sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) command line utility is also located in the SQL Server’s Tools\Binn sub-directory. To execute a SQL script:

1. Start the Command Prompt
2. Navigate to the folder where the sqlcmd utility is located
3. Run a command in the following format:

   sqlcmd –S <server name> -d <database name> -i <full path to script> -U <user login ID> –P <login password>

To execute the same as above, run the following command:

```
sqlcmd -S Dell\SQL2012 -d Central -i D:\test\large.sql -U sa –P sqladmin
```

[Start the sqlcmd Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166559.aspx)
[Run Transact-SQL Script Files Using sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx)

Comment: thnks, but again i got an error like " Msg 102,Level 15, State 1, Server ABC, Line 32 Incorrect syntax near '38' "

Comment: You can try ApexSQL Run Script utility, it might help. It's free. You can find more info about it here: http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/synchronizing-huge-databases/. Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a support engineer

Answer (score 1):

I use [sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to execute large SQL files.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate script of your database by RightClick on your database Tasks>GenerateScripts> click next on Generate and Script window Check on select specific table choose tables you want Press next Click on Advance option on end of General Category select Type of data to script now choose which kind you want your database to.
Scheme Only: Means this script will create your database.
DataOnly:If you have created database and table this will insert data into it.
Press ok then Next.
Your file is by default save in
C:\Users[UserName]\Documents\ .