# Importing Big SQL Dump File into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Excuse me, I generate SQL File with insert command like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515969/exporting-data-in-sql-server-as-insert-into)

Then, the file contains many lines, and when I open it with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the program can not open it..

How can I run this dump of sql file scripts?

The SQL dump file is large.

Comment: Define *large* - are we talking about thousands, hundreds of thousands, millions of rows? You should check into `SQLCMD` - the command-line SQL utility for SQL Server

Comment: 389 MB it contains 668919 lines, some lines is so long, like html content, and if I open the file using notepad++, it takes some minutes

Comment: i found this: this case is same with my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853153/how-to-execute-generated-script-sql-file-with-schema-and-data-in-sql-server-20